# Conversion fails when converting date average to date in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have calculated a date average from several dates and I'm trying to get the result of the average date, but I'm getting the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Here's the SQL query I tried:

```
select 
    CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(convert(varchar(10), AVG(convert(int, convert(varchar(10), OnMarkDate, 112)))), 8))
from 
    @tbl_XMLResult
```

Here are the date values in table `@tbl_XMLResult`:

```
   '2001-10-11',
   '2001-10-03',
   '2001-09-24',
   '2000-05-31',
   '2001-10-15',
   '2008-01-01'
```

These dates are of type `date`.

Comment: The "average" date comes out as `20020764` - so the 64th day of the 7th month of 2002 (or the 7th day of the 64th month) ??? How is this even ***useful*** ?!?!!?!??! What do you **really** want to achieve here???

Comment: As per dates given in column above I want to calculate the average date as a result. For minimum and maximum date I can find it out with Min and Max aggregate function but Avg function is not directly give me average date result, and that's what I want is..

Comment: You need to define what *average date* means - quite obviously, converting the date `2001-10-11` to an arbitrary `INT` and then taking the average of those int values **doesn't work** .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

I calculate the differences in days from the oldest date (`2000-05-31`) in the first CTE, then I calculate the average of those day differences (all `int` values), and then I add this average to the oldest date, to get an "average" date.

```
DECLARE @input TABLE (OnMarkDate DATE)

INSERT INTO @input (OnMarkDate)
VALUES ('2001-10-11'), ('2001-10-03'), ('2001-09-24'),
       ('2000-05-31'), ('2001-10-15'), ('2008-01-01');

DECLARE @OldestDate DATE = '2000-05-31';    

;WITH DateAndDayDiff AS 
(
    SELECT DayDiff = DATEDIFF(DAY, @OldestDate, OnMarkDate)
    FROM @INPUT
), AverageDayDiff AS 
(
    SELECT AverageDiff = AVG(DayDiff)
    FROM DateAndDayDiff 
)
SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, AverageDayDiff.AverageDiff, @OldestDate)
FROM AverageDayDiff
```

When I do this, I get `2002-07-30` as the "average" date for this list of dates.